# How to omit error : [ts] The inferred type of <class function name> references an inaccessible 'this' type. A type annotation is necessary

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, typescript2.0, vscode-debugger

I wanna create very nice, fluent typescript api, but I am getting
error:

> [ts] The inferred type of 'firstLevelFunction' references an inaccessible 'this'
>   type. A type annotation is necessary.

My class schema:

```
class SomeClassAPI { 

    // in my case (on the picture at bottom)
    // 'firstLevelFunction(...)' equal 'replace(...)' method ,
    // from class CodeTransform  )
    public firstLevelFunction() { 
        const self = this; // ERROR
        // const self = this as any; // OK but not typechecking

        return {
            secondLevelFunction() {
                return {
                    thirdLevelFunction() {
                        // ....
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only if I am doing api with 'thirdLevelFunction' I am getting this thing.
**How can I omit this error** ?

my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "declaration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types"
        ],
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015"
        ],
        "types": [
            "node"
        ],
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "outDir": "dist"
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "preview",
        "docs",
        "dist",
        "bundle",
        "example",
        "examples",
        "tests",
        "tmp-src"
    ]
}
```

This is how error looks like in vscode:

[image]

I am using:

- **typescript** 2.6.2
- **vscode** 1.21.1
- **mac osx** 10.13.3

Comment: Can you be a little bit clearer about exactly where the error is occurring? You don't mention `isomorphic` or `replace()` in your description. Also, the code you provide above is not valid TypeScript (no brackets around the class definition). Perhaps posting a minimal example where you can reproduce the issue would be helpful.

Comment: @err1100 try to use now class `SomeClassAPI` inside vscode with tsconig.json (above).

Comment: I do not receive any intellisense errors from VSCode, nor compiler errors from `tsc`, when I copy and paste the code you provided, create a new instance of SomeClassAPI, and call `firstLevelFunction()`.

Comment: hmm i got this error too. any luck?

Answer (score -2):

I just had this error message.

It goes away when you explicitly specify the type of the function's return value: `public replace(): any {...}`

I guess TS cannot infere the return type in this specific case.

Comment: It actually worked for me